# Html.ActionLink with more than one route value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink, html.actionlink

I have a problem with `Html.ActionLink`method.

If I use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Some text", "MyAction", "MyController", new { id = 1234 }, null)
```

I get a link with this href:

```
http://web.com/MyController/MyAction/1234
```

That is fine, but if I use more route values like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Some text", "MyAction", "MyController", new { id = 1234, param1 = 3, param2 = 10 }, null)
```

I get a link with this href:

```
http://web.com/MyController/MyAction/1234?param1=3&param2=10
```

But I need:

```
http://web.com/MyController/MyAction/1234/3/10
```

Do you know how can I get it?

**Edition to give more info:**

In MyController code file I have that:

```
[Route("MyController/MyAction/{id}")]
public ActionResult MyAction(string id) { /* some code */ }

[Route("MyController/MyAction/{id}/{param1}/{param2}")]
public ActionResult MyAction(string id, byte param1, byte param2) { /* some code */ }
```

And this is my RouteCofig.cs file:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this attribute `[Route("MyController/MyAction/{id}/{param1}/{param2}")]` in the action `public ActionResult MyAction(string id, byte param1, byte param2)`, I thought that there were the same thing.

Comment: can you show us your route config?

Comment: Question edited with controller and route config. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please try use route from my answer.

Comment: Yes, it is "`MyControllerController"`. If I use Alexandru's answer it works, but I would like to unsdertand what is the difference between adding a `MapRoute` in `RouteConfig` or using the `Route` attribute in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution,

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "MyRoute",                                           // Route name
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{param1}/{param2}",                          // URL with parameters
        defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction", id = "", param1="", param2="" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```